# Where are the thumbnails and the photos themselves from the Google Photos iOS app saved on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, storage, google-photos

Photos taken with the iPhone camera are saved in DCIM I believe and the thumbnails are stored \var\mobile\Media\PhotoData, as ithmb files I also believe.

Where would the Google Photos app on iOS keep its thumbnails and photos? The same place or within the app’s data location?

If it’s stored somewhere in the Google Photos app data section of the phone, would deleting the app remove any and all of these thumbnails from the device if the photos are deleted, getting rid of the thumbnails when the google photos app is restored?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

(Almost all) data an app generates is deleted when the app is deleted. Google Photos certainly would not store data alongside the iOS Photos app.